# Linux: How to preserve read-only mode for layered bind mounts

Tags: linux, shell, mount, fstab, bind

Let’s give some context to the issue:

1. There is `/foo/bar` directory in read-write mode
2. There is `/bar` bind mount that points to `/foo/bar`
3. In `/foo/bar` there is `bar` directory that has to be in read-only mode (both `/foo/bar/baz` and `/bar/baz`)

In order to make `/foo/bar/baz` be read-only I do this another bind:

```
$ sudo mount -o bind,ro /foo/bar/baz /foo/bar/baz
$ sudo touch /foo/bar/baz/test
touch: cannot touch '/foo/bar/baz/test': Read-only file system
$ mount | grep bar
/dev/vda1 on /bar type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
/dev/vda1 on /foo/bar/baz type xfs (ro,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
/dev/vda1 on /bar/baz type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
```

*P.S. There is `/foo/bar/baz` and `/bar/baz` but the latter is not read-only.*

But `/bar/baz` is writable:

```
$ sudo touch /bar/baz/test
$ echo $?
0
```

Trying to make another bind:

```
$ sudo mount -o bind,ro /bar/baz /bar/baz
$ mount | grep bar
/dev/vda1 on /bar type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
/dev/vda1 on /foo/bar/baz type xfs (ro,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
/dev/vda1 on /bar/baz type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
/dev/vda1 on /bar/baz type xfs (ro,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
/dev/vda1 on /foo/bar/baz type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
/dev/vda1 on /foo/bar/baz type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
/dev/vda1 on /bar/baz type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
```

What really confuses me:

1. Why are there 3 the same mounts for `/bar/baz` now? There was none and after one bind I get three:

   ```
   /dev/vda1 on /bar/baz type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
   /dev/vda1 on /bar/baz type xfs (ro,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
   /dev/vda1 on /bar/baz type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
   ```

   Two are read-write and one read-only. Which one takes the priority? It seems the read-only one:

   ```
   $ sudo touch /bar/baz/test
   touch: cannot touch '/bar/baz/test': Read-only file system
   ```

   But it’s not the last one, the read-only one is in the middle.
2. Why there are now 3 mounts for `/foo/bar/baz`, there was just read-only one and now I have 3:

   ```
   /dev/vda1 on /foo/bar/baz type xfs (ro,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
   /dev/vda1 on /foo/bar/baz type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
   /dev/vda1 on /foo/bar/baz type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
   ```

   One read-only and two read-write. What takes the priority? Turns out not the read-only one since it’s writable:

   ```
   $ sudo touch /foo/bar/baz/test
   $ echo $?
   0
   ```

Why does it happen? And how to avoid it? What is the correct way to make both `/foo/bar/baz` and `/bar/baz` be read-only at the same time?

Comment: Please copy to the question the output of `grep bar /proc/self/mountinfo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation part is perfectly covered in *aviro*’s answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/689950/513617

I found a good solution that doesn’t add any extra read-write mounts. It’s `remount` option.

1. `mount -o bind /foo/bar /bar`
2. `mount -o bind,ro /foo/bar/baz /foo/bar/baz`
3. And then take the existing read-write `/bar/baz` propagated bind and `remount` it:
   `mount -o bind,ro,remount /foo/bar/baz /bar/baz`

After that you get only these:

```
$ mount | grep bar
/dev/vda1 on /bar type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
/dev/vda1 on /foo/bar/baz type xfs (ro,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
/dev/vda1 on /bar/baz type xfs (ro,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,logbufs=8,logbsize=32k,noquota)
```

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

By default, `/bar` and `/foo/bar` are **shared** mounts. This means that after you bind mount something on a folder in `/foo/bar`, it is propagated to `/bar`, but **also** when you mount something on a folder in `/bar`, it will be propagated back to `/foo/bar`.

From the man pages of `mount(8)`:

> ... A shared mount provides the ability to create mirrors of that mount
> such that mounts and unmounts within any of the mirrors propagate to
> the other mirror. ...

Since you bind mount `/bar/baz` on `/bar/baz`, it is propagated back to `/foo/bar/baz` (as `rw`).

There are two options:

#### Option #1

Instead of running:

```
mount -o bind,ro /bar/baz /bar/baz
```

Run:

```
mount -o bind,ro /foo/bar/baz /bar/baz
```

Since you now mount from the original `/foo/bar`, it wouldn't get propagated back there.

#### Option #2

You need to make `/bar` a **slave** of `/foo/bar`.

Again, from the man pages of `mount(8)`:

> ... A slave mount receives  propagation from its master, but not vice
> versa. ...

So instead of running:

```
mount -o bind /foo/bar /bar
```

Run:

```
mount --make-rslave -o bind /foo/bar /bar
```

That the only difference. Then you can bind mount `/foo/bar/baz` as read-only (at which point `/bar/baz` is still read/write), and then bind mount `/bar/baz` as read-only, without interfering with the read-only bind mount you previously created on `/foo/bar/baz`.

### Explaining the problem

If we recreate your steps, we'll see the following:

#### (1) `mount -o bind /foo/bar /bar`

You can see the result in `/proc/self/mountinfo`.

In order to understand the different fields, you need to read man pages of `proc(5)`:

```
/proc/[pid]/mountinfo (since Linux 2.6.26)
       This file contains information about mount points.  It contains lines of the form:

       36 35 98:0 /mnt1 /mnt2 rw,noatime master:1 - ext3 /dev/root rw,errors=continue
       (1)(2)(3)   (4)   (5)      (6)      (7)   (8) (9)   (10)         (11)

       The numbers in parentheses are labels for the descriptions below:

       (1)  mount ID: unique identifier of the mount (may be reused after umount(2)).

       (2)  parent ID: ID of parent mount (or of self for the top of the mount tree).
```

Now let's check `/proc/self/mountinfo`:

```
# grep bar /proc/self/mountinfo
146 65 8:1 /foo/bar /bar rw,relatime shared:1 - xfs /dev/sda1 rw,attr2,inode64,logbsize=256k,sunit=512,swidth=512,noquota

# grep ^65 /proc/self/mountinfo
65 0 8:1 / / rw,relatime shared:1 - xfs /dev/sda1 rw,attr2,inode64,logbsize=256k,sunit=512,swidth=512,noquota
```

1. Mount ID **146**, is `/foo/bar` which is mounted on `/bar`.
2. It's parent ID is **65**, which is the root partition (`/`).

Also, notice that `/foo/bar` is mounted on `/bar` as **shared**.

#### (2) `mount -o bind,ro /foo/bar/baz /foo/bar/baz`

1. This creates a read-only bind mount from /foo/bar/baz to /foo/bar/baz.
2. It's also propagated to `/bar` which means that `/foo/bar/baz` is also mounted on `/bar/baz`.
3. But as I said, the `ro` option is not propagated, so `/bar/baz` is still `rw`.

You can see it in `/proc/self/mountinfo`:

```
# grep bar /proc/self/mountinfo
146 65 8:1 /foo/bar /bar rw,relatime shared:1 - xfs /dev/sda1 rw,attr2,inode64,logbsize=256k,sunit=512,swidth=512,noquota
182 65 8:1 /foo/bar/baz /foo/bar/baz ro,relatime shared:1 - xfs /dev/sda1 rw,attr2,inode64,logbsize=256k,sunit=512,swidth=512,noquota
183 146 8:1 /foo/bar/baz /bar/baz rw,relatime shared:1 - xfs /dev/sda1 rw,attr2,inode64,logbsize=256k,sunit=512,swidth=512,noquota
```

*1.* **182** `/foo/bar/baz` is mounted on top `/foo/bar/baz` as `ro` as a result **(2)**

*2.* **146** `/foo/bar` is mounted on `/bar` as a result of **(1)**.

- **183** `/foo/bar/baz` is then mounted again on top of `/bar/baz` as `rw` as a result **(2)**.

It is important notice is that the mount options (for instance, `ro`) are not propagated along with the mount. `/foo/bar/baz` was propagated to `/bar/baz`, but without the `ro` option.

So now `/foo/bar/baz` is mounted once on `/foo/bar/baz` (as read-only), and once on `/bar/baz` (as read/write, as a result of the propagation from `/foo/bar`).

#### (3) `mount -o bind,ro /bar/baz /bar/baz`

1. This creates a read-only bind mount from /bar/baz to /bar/baz.
2. It's also propagated to `/foo/bar` which means that `/bar/baz` is also mounted on `/foo/bar/baz`.
3. But again, the `ro` option is not propagated, so `/foo/bar/baz` is now read-write.

```
# grep bar /proc/self/mountinfo
146 65 8:1 /foo/bar /bar rw,relatime shared:1 - xfs /dev/sda1 rw,attr2,inode64,logbsize=256k,sunit=512,swidth=512,noquota
182 202 8:1 /foo/bar/baz /foo/bar/baz ro,relatime shared:1 - xfs /dev/sda1 rw,attr2,inode64,logbsize=256k,sunit=512,swidth=512,noquota
183 201 8:1 /foo/bar/baz /bar/baz rw,relatime shared:1 - xfs /dev/sda1 rw,attr2,inode64,logbsize=256k,sunit=512,swidth=512,noquota
200 183 8:1 /foo/bar/baz /bar/baz ro,relatime shared:1 - xfs /dev/sda1 rw,attr2,inode64,logbsize=256k,sunit=512,swidth=512,noquota
203 182 8:1 /foo/bar/baz /foo/bar/baz rw,relatime shared:1 - xfs /dev/sda1 rw,attr2,inode64,logbsize=256k,sunit=512,swidth=512,noquota
202 65 8:1 /foo/bar/baz /foo/bar/baz rw,relatime shared:1 - xfs /dev/sda1 rw,attr2,inode64,logbsize=256k,sunit=512,swidth=512,noquota
201 146 8:1 /foo/bar/baz /bar/baz rw,relatime shared:1 - xfs /dev/sda1 rw,attr2,inode64,logbsize=256k,sunit=512,swidth=512,noquota
```

*1.* **146** `/foo/bar` is mounted on `/bar` as a result of **(1)**.

- **201** `/foo/bar/baz` is mounted on `/bar/baz`.

  - **183** `/foo/bar/baz` is then mounted again on top of `/bar/baz` as `rw` as a result **(2)**

    - **200** `/foo/bar/baz` the mounted **again** on top of `/bar/baz` is `ro` as a result of **(3)**.

*2.*  **202** `/foo/bar/baz` is the original folder on `/`.

- **182** `/foo/bar/baz` is mounted on top `/foo/bar/baz` as `ro` as a result **(2)**

  - **203** `/foo/bar/baz` is mounted **again** on `/foo/bar/baz` as `rw` as a result of **(3)**.

Now `/foo/bar/baz` is mounted once on `/bar/baz` (as read-only), and once on `/foo/bar/baz` (as read/write).

### Solution

#### (1) `mount --make-rslave -o bind /foo/bar /bar`

```
# grep bar /proc/self/mountinfo
146 65 8:1 /foo/bar /bar rw,relatime master:1 - xfs /dev/sda1 rw,attr2,inode64,logbsize=256k,sunit=512,swidth=512,noquota
```

Now `/foo/bar` is the **master** of `/bar`: You can propagate mounts from `/foo/bar` to `/bar`, but mounts on `/bar` will not be propagated back to `/foo/bar`.

#### (2) `mount -o bind,ro /foo/bar/baz /foo/bar/baz`

```
# grep bar /proc/self/mountinfo
146 65 8:1 /foo/bar /bar rw,relatime master:1 - xfs /dev/sda1 rw,attr2,inode64,logbsize=256k,sunit=512,swidth=512,noquota
182 65 8:1 /foo/bar/baz /foo/bar/baz ro,relatime shared:1 - xfs /dev/sda1 rw,attr2,inode64,logbsize=256k,sunit=512,swidth=512,noquota
183 146 8:1 /foo/bar/baz /bar/baz rw,relatime master:1 - xfs /dev/sda1 rw,attr2,inode64,logbsize=256k,sunit=512,swidth=512,noquota
```

It similar to what we've seen before, only now `/foo/bar` is the master of `/bar`, and `/foo/bar/baz` is the master of `/bar/baz`.

#### (3) `mount -o bind,ro /bar/baz /bar/baz`

```
# grep bar /proc/self/mountinfo
146 65 8:1 /foo/bar /bar rw,relatime master:1 - xfs /dev/sda1 rw,attr2,inode64,logbsize=256k,sunit=512,swidth=512,noquota
182 65 8:1 /foo/bar/baz /foo/bar/baz ro,relatime shared:1 - xfs /dev/sda1 rw,attr2,inode64,logbsize=256k,sunit=512,swidth=512,noquota
183 146 8:1 /foo/bar/baz /bar/baz rw,relatime master:1 - xfs /dev/sda1 rw,attr2,inode64,logbsize=256k,sunit=512,swidth=512,noquota
200 183 8:1 /foo/bar/baz /bar/baz ro,relatime master:1 - xfs /dev/sda1 rw,attr2,inode64,logbsize=256k,sunit=512,swidth=512,noquota
```

This is the main difference: Now only new mount was created, number **200**.

The rest didn't change. This mount wasn't propagated back to `/foo/bar`, so `/foo/bar/baz` is still mounted on `/foo/bar/baz` as `ro` as a result of **(2)**.

So now `/foo/bar/baz` is mounted as read-only on both `/foo/bar/baz` and `/bar/baz`.

Comment: Thanks for very useful explanation and good examples! Though still with this solution I still have extra `rw` mount for `/bar/baz` which doesn’t have to be there. I found another solution — “remount” option which I will post separately.